# How to substract from count of 2 results in mysql query

Tags: mysql

I am new to mysql. I have 2 seperate queries which give me counts.

I want to get [COUNT 1 - COUNT 2]. But, I don't know how to do it in mysql.

Below is my query

```
(select COUNT(CITY) as M from STATION) 
MINUS
(select COUNT(DISTINCT CITY) as N from STATION)
```

Error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-
(select COUNT(DISTINCT CITY) as N from STATION)' at line 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in single query like

```
SELECT COUNT(CITY) - COUNT(DISTINCT CITY)
FROM STATION
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved

select 
((select COUNT(CITY) as M from STATION) 
MINUS
(select COUNT(DISTINCT CITY) as N from STATION)) as count
from STATION LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0):

Try this query !

SELECT
              COUNT(CITY)
               - 
              COUNT(DISTINCT CITY) 
AS 
             'M-N'
FROM
             STATION